# SQL - Comparing two rows in a table and exclude from search

Tags: sql

I checked other forum topics related to row comparison but those are not the thing I am seeking.
I want to compare two rows and if there is a match between them, they should be excluded from the SELECT
I have one table

```
  CREATE table Customers (
   RoomID INT,
   First_Name varChar(255),
   Last_Name varChar(255),
   Place_of_Birth varChar(255)
  )
```

With these users

```
 Insert into Customers (
   150,
  'Mark',
  'James',
  'Las Vegas'
 )
 Insert into Customers (
   120,
  'Deidre',
  'Hanks',
  'London'
 )
 Insert into Customers (
   150,
   'Jack',
   'Slims',
   'Vienna'
 )
 Insert into Customers (
   130,
   'Anna-maria',
   'Garnet',
   'Paris'
 )
```

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [RoomID]
  ,[First_Name]
  ,[Last_Name]
  ,[Place_of_Birth]
FROM [Exercise].[dbo].[Customers]
```

Now here is what I want
If **RoomID = 150** and **Place_of_Birth = Vienna**, then **exclude** row where **RoomID = 150** and **Place_of_Birth = Las Vegas** 
Bluntly speaking:
If one row that shares Same column value, but each contains a different value in another column, don't include it in the SELECT 
Using the WHERE function, I can exclude one specific row for example, that display rows that does not contain "Vienna" but that is not what I am looking for
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable   
WHERE RoomId NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT RoomId
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE RoomId = 150 AND Place_of_Birth = 'Vienna'
)
```

The subquery here will return all RoomId's where your combined statement is true, and the **NOT EXISTS** will exclude these from the returned results.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is really to only return those rows which have no duplicates in *RoomID* except when the *Place_of_Birth* is identical the following should do the job:

```
select * from t
where RoomID not in
(
  select RoomID
  from t
  group by RoomID having min(Place_of_Birth) != max(Place_of_Birth)
)
```

[try online](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vE4aF7jWSKVCHZkcD2AJEz/0)